# Accountless synchronisation of App settings

Tags: flutter, windows, synchronization, settings

I know that Windows supports synchronisation of App settings, but I couldn't really figure out which APIs I can actually use for that. I just found out that this seems to be limited to Apps distributed via the Microsoft Store. Is that true so far?

I would like to integrate it in my Flutter App, and therefore I cannot directly use the .NET framework. I found out that there is an [App settings API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data). Can I use this with NativeAOT with .NET Core so that I can use [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface)?

I know that I can do that simply with a Login, but I want it accountless without a login with the system APIs.

Can you point me to the right documentation? My main issue is that I don't have any experience what is compatible and what not. I just want to avoid wasting time with implementing an incompatible API.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Dart language projection for the `Windows.Storage` API in the [`windows_storage`](https://pub.dev/packages/windows_storage) package. You can access the roaming settings (and other available storage) through the `ApplicationData` object:

```dart
settings = ApplicationData.current!.roamingSettings!;
settings.values!['darkMode'] = true;

// ...

final theme = (settings.values!['darkMode'] as bool? ?? true)
  ? ThemeData.dark()
  : ThemeData.light();
```

Unfortunately `ApplicationData.current` throws an exception if Windows cannot determine an application identity for the process, so you'll probably need additional logic to ignore the roaming data store during development.

Even more unfortunately, the entire roaming data system might be moot. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#roaming-data) state:

> Roaming data and settings is no longer supported as of Windows 11. The recommended replacement is Azure App Service. Azure App Service is widely supported, well documented, reliable, and supports cross-platform/cross-ecosystem scenarios such as iOS, Android and web.
>
> The following documentation applies to Windows 10 versions 1909 and lower.

Comment: So you recommend a discontinued API? Does that Azure App Service require a login? The cross platform feature looks bit like that. :-/

Comment: Azure App Services is seemingly just Azure's backend as a service offering, so yes it would require some sort of user account to sync data. Personally I would look into Supabase or other BaaS offerings with first-class Flutter SDKs before resorting to Azure.

If you see Windows store apps syncing without login it's possible the API is still up past the deprecation notice. Do you have any examples of apps that exhibit this behavior on Windows 11? I'd be interesting in examining them if so.

Comment: I am not aware of any app which has that feature, but I read in the past that this feature should exist. But to be honest I almost never use the Microsoft Store. I just want to know if there is an equivalent API of BlockStore (from Android) or the iCloud's Key-Value storage (from Apple). None of those APIs require a login just the same user (account) on the device. My usecase is that you (install and) start the app on a new device and the app knows you directly.

Comment: > I just want to know if there is an equivalent API of BlockStore (from Android) or the iCloud's Key-Value storage (from Apple).

There was (the roaming storage we've been discussing), but unfortunately Microsoft killed it in Windows 11. There is no replacement API that I am aware of.